# Infinitely many primes of the form 8k+5

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to answer this as a homework question, so I'm only looking for hints.

I have just proved that $x^2+1 \equiv 0\pmod{p} \iff p=2\vee p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, so I assume this will be useful.

Comment: Dirichlet proved a theorem that says there are infinitely many primes in *every* arithmetic progression.  But I guess you aren't allowed to quote that theorem.

Comment: Step 1: Use your work to prove there are infinitely many primes of the form 8k+5 or 8k+1.  Step 2: Assume all but finitely many are of the form 8k+1.

Comment: I assume that $\mod 0$ should read $\mod p$?

Comment: according to [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), $8k+5$ generates an infinite amount of prime numbers, since $8$ and $5$ are coprime integers.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $p_1,p_2,\dots, p_n$ be primes of the form $8k+5$. Consider the number $(p_1p_2\cdots p_n)^2+4$.  And yes, the result you quoted will be useful.

Remark: Variants of the above idea will take care of primes of form $8k+3$ and $8k+7$, but not $8k+1$.

Comment: why do we take +4? Is there any intuitive reason why numbers of this form work?

Comment: @Mark There is a general result that if $p=4k+3$ is a prime and $p\mid a^2+b^2$, then $p\mid a,p\mid b$. A contrapositive of this should be used here.

Comment: @Mark  You need a divisor of form $5$ mod $8$.  For this to have a chance to  work you essentially need the number itself to be in that class as itself could be the only divisor (except $1$).

Comment: @Mark: Why $+4$? (i) Because  we  get a number of the form $4k+5$ and (ii) Because if the prime $p$ divides our number, then $x^2\equiv -4\pmod{p}$ has a solution, and therefore $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has a solution.