# Prove that there are infinity primes $p$ such that $2$ is not a quadratic residue $\mod{p}$

Tags: number-theory

I know it has to do with the Legendre symbol, but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658441/infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-8k5

Comment: There is a general formula for the relevant Legendre symbols:
$ \left(\frac 2 p \right) = \begin{cases} + 1, & p \equiv \pm 1 \mod 8 \\ -1, & p \equiv \pm 3 \mod 8\end{cases}$.  
Perhaps you're asked to dig up a proof of this result, or perhaps you're simply asked to make use of it, but in any case, this is a good place to start.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221582/if-p-congruent-to-1-bmod-8-then-2p-1-2-1-divisible-by-p.

Answer (score 0):

By the formula for the Legendre symbol, $(2/p)$ then $2$ is a quadratic
nonresidue modulo $p$ iff $p\equiv\pm3\pmod 8$. For any integer $N$,
$8N+3$ has a prime factor $p$ congruent to $\pm3\pmod 8$. Take $N$ to be a product of a lot of primes, excluding $3$. Then $p\ne3$ and $p$
isn't a factor of $N$. So we can get a prime outside any finite set of
primes for which $2$ is a quadratic nonresidue.

Comment: How does $8N+3$ have a prime factor congruent to $3 \mod 8$?

Comment: @edm It may not, e.g., $35$ doesn't.